# Store data in array from input fields in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, authentication

I want to store data in an existing array from a login form.

this is where i want to store my data.

```
const usersAccount = [
    {
      username: "user1",
      password: "pass1"
    }
  ];
```

and this is the function that get called on submit of the form

```
  // check user when try to register
  const registerUser = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    var { uname, pass } = document.forms[0];
    const username = uname.value;
    const password = pass.value;

    console.log(username, password);
  };
```

username and password are the values i want to past in the **userAccount**
the form is an usual login form with 2 input fields and one button with `type='submit'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not using any state management handlers for storing credentials?.
If you want to store credentials in exisiting array.

```
    const registerUser = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      var { uname, pass } = document.forms[0];
      const username = uname.value;
      const password = pass.value;
      usersAccount[0].username = username
      usersAccount[0].password = password
   };
```

But, using the above approach is a bad way of storing credential.

---

A good approach could be to store the existing array as in the **useState**

```
const [cred,setCred] = useState(usersAccount)

const registerUser = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  var { uname, pass } = document.forms[0];
  const username = uname.value;
  const password = pass.value;
  const newUserPass = {username, password}
  setCred([...newUserPass])
};
```